# Assigning Label Value with Selected Table View Cell

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, storyboard

I am making Xcode newsfeed application with storyboard.

I have a table which consist of subject titles. I also have a title label beside the table to show what is the title of the article.

What do I want now is, when the user click on the table cell, the title label should change to the selected subject title.

Here is my code to do that:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *subjectCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    titleLabel.text = subjectCell.textLabel.text;
}
```

However, here is what happen as I clicked the table cell:
1. First, I clicked on subject 1 and the title Label does not changed to subject 1.
2. I tried to click on subject 2 and the title label changed to subject 1.
3. I clicked on subject 3 and the title label changed to subject 2.

It seems like the title label does not respond immediately when the cell is clicked.
How can I fix this?

[image: Title Label Does not Match!]

Thank You,
Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you are using `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath`, change it to `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  UITableViewCell *subjectCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
  titleLabel.text = subjectCell.textLabel.text;
}
```

Comment: oh my god.. Can't believe I made this mistake. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
NSInteger *subject = indexPath.row;
subject + 1;
NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:subject inSection:0];
```

You're simply adding 1 to the index path, since it is displaying the row before the one you are wanting to display! :)

Hope it helps!